# How to sort a dataset in SAS so records are interleaved?

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a dataset:

```
data animals;
   input animal  $
         group   $
         control $;
datalines;
dog A c1
dog B c1
dog C c1
dog D c2
dog E c2
dog F c2
dog G c3
dog H c3
dog I c3
;
run;
```

I would like that to be sorted in such a way that the resulting dataset looks like:

```
dog A c1
dog D c2
dog G c3
dog B c1
dog E c2
dog H c3
dog C c1
dog F c2
dog I c3
```

I don't see any special options for proc sort that would do an "alternating" sort, so I will probably have to subset my dataset "BY control", then recombine in a data step in such a way that they interleave/alternate.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you want to achieve? I don't see any pattern in the second dataset. Also, you are talking about combining two data sets, while I only see one.

Comment: I changed the title to reflect my general question.  Notice how the third column in the resulting dataset (the second code box in my question) goes c1,c2,c3 and repeats.  See what I mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
proc sort data= animals out= animals2;
    by control group;
run;

data animals2;
    set animals2;
    by control;
    retain orderWithinControlType;
    if first.control then orderWithinControlType = 1;
    else orderWithinControlType +1;
run;

proc sort data= animals2 out= animals3;
    by orderWithinControlType control;
run;

proc print data= animals3;
run;
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you.  I'm glad this solution doesn't require a bunch of crazy subsetting.